# ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()

Tags: python, redis, celery

I've a *deep learning* model. To query the model I use celery to make it asynchronous, as number of query requests is very large. The number of workers that spins up while starting the service is equal to number of *cores* that is available in the system. For example if I have a 8 core machine, it'll spin up 8 workers.

I use the following line to do asynchronous request using celery:

`response = flask_with_celery.inference.apply_async((service_id, locale, query), queue='inference')`

where `inference` is a `celery` task function. `redis` is the backend for `celery` here.

I do performance testing using `jmeter`. The testing is being done for 10 minutes for `x` concurrent users. I try the value of `x` here with `20`, `30`, `40`, `50`, `100`.

After some time, at the end of `50` concurrent users or start of `100` concurrent users, the code throws error.

```
[2018-11-12 14:36:12,815] ERROR in app: Exception on /process_qna_query [POST]
   File "site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
   File "site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
   File "site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
   File "site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
   File "site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
   File "site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
   File "site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
   File "FAQ.py", line 103, in json_test
   File "site-packages/celery/result.py", line 194, in get
   File "site-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 189, in wait_for_pending
   File "site-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 256, in _wait_for_pending
   File "site-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 57, in drain_events_until
   File "site-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 66, in wait_for
   File "site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 69, in drain_events
   File "site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2513, in get_message
   File "site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2428, in parse_response
   File "site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 619, in can_read
 ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
```

If I start testing for `100` conc users first, then `50` and so on. I get the error when testing with `20` concurrent users. Clearly it's not about number of users. The number of request it gets for `100` users in `10` minutes is roughly the same as number of request it gets for `20` users.

*Edit*: I changed the celery results backend to `memcached` and I'm not getting any errors!